# Divisibility property $\pm a \mid \pm b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that given $a,b \in \mathbb {Z}; a \mid b$ and $b \mid a$, then $a = \pm b$, as follows:

Case (i) : For $\exists u,v \in \mathbb {Z}$, such that for $a|b, b = au$, and for $b|a, a = bv$.

Substituting $a = bv$ in $b = au$, we get : $uv = 1$. Hence, $u,v = \pm 1$, as $u,v \in \mathbb {Z}$.

Now, considering the next 3 cases with first two cases building on case (i), and the last case on case (ii) and (iii).

Case (ii): For $(-a)|b$, let $\exists v^{'} (= -u)\in \mathbb {Z}$ such that $b = v^{'}a$. The multiplier chosen is $-1$ for $u$, as the only possible value for $u,v$ is $\pm 1$, and it solves the case as shown next.

$b = v^{'}a => b = (-u)(-a) => b = ua$.

So, $(-a)|b$.

Case (iii): For $(-b)|a$, let $\exists u^{'} (= -v)\in \mathbb {Z}$ such that $a = u^{'}b$. The multiplier chosen is $-1$ for $v$, as the only possible value for $u,v$ is $\pm 1$, and it solves the case as shown next.

$a = u^{'}b => a = (-v)(-b) => a = vb$.

So, $(-b)|a$.

Case (iv): Taking cue from cases (ii) & (iii), and merging the two cases in one; we get:

For $(-a)|b$, let $\exists v^{'} (= -u)\in \mathbb {Z}$ such that $b = v^{'}a$.

For $(-b)|a$, let $\exists u^{'} (= -v)\in \mathbb {Z}$ such that $a = u^{'}b$.

This hopefully solves the case (iv) too.

Comment: Are you sure, that $a, b\in\mathbb{N}$? From $a|b$ you get $a\leq b$ and from $b|a$ you get $b\leq a$. Hence $a=b$.

Comment: If both divide each other, then in that case definitely yes.

Comment: sorry, sign has to be accommodated, I have done the edit.

Comment: You do not need 3 cases.

Comment: "Now, considering the next 3 cases with first two cases building on case (i)"  What? Why????? Aren't you done? $a|b \implies b =au$ and $b|a\implies a =bw$ so $b=buw$ so $uw=1$ so $u=w=\pm 1$ and $b = au = \pm a$.  What the heck are *THREE* more cases for?

Comment: Can say that it is redundant, but for proving the theorem that if $a|b$ and $b|a$, then $a = \pm b$, it is better for beginners like me. I am a beginner, and need be meticulous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ there are $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$au=b$ and $bv=a$. We get:

$au=bvu=b$. Hence $vu=1$ and $u=v^{-1}$. Therefore $u,v\in\{\pm 1\}=\mathbb{Z}^\ast$ (the group of units in $\mathbb{Z}$).

Finally $a=\pm b$